# Facebook Graph API - Accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently trying to use the Facebook Graph API to get data for a closed group's photo albums. It being closed, I need to get a page access token first.

So to get my page access token, I would do this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{my-id}/accounts?access_token={my-token}
```

However, all I get back is :

```
{
"data": [
   ]
}
```

I'm an admin on the page I'm trying to pull photos from and I even created a test Facebook group yesterday to see if it was just the group acting up but still nothing.

Here is a list of the scope of my access token:

```
user_managed_groups, user_photos, user_friends, read_stream, read_mailbox, email, manage_pages, read_custom_friendlists, public_profile
```

Is there anything I'm missing or any other way to go about this?

Edit:
Ideally I want to pull photo URLs from a group's album. The problem I'm coming across is that when I do /{album-id}/photos, an empty JSON is returned. I'm assuming it's because the group is closed and an access token is needed but when I do /me/groups/, only "administrator":"boolean" is returned. Where do I get a group access token?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Not getting a Page Access Token? What has creating a group have to do with pulling photos from a page? That's two completely different questions...!

Comment: I edited the question, sorry it was a bit confusing

Comment: There's no such thing as a group Access Token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/me/accounts` returns Pages, not Groups.

`/me/groups` is what you need, and a User Access Token with `user_managed_groups`.

I suggest NOT using your ID, but "me" instead.

Btw, i believe access to group photos is limited. There is not even an album or photos endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group

Comment: please read my answer again. you are trying to use the /accounts endpoint, which is for pages. and there is no group access token. i´ve explained everything you need to know, the rest is in the docs. just authorize a user with user_managed_groups.

Comment: i´ve added some more information about albums/photos of groups btw

Comment: There's an `/v2.3/{group_id}/albums` endpoint, but it's not documented. Check `/v2.3/{group_id}?metadata=1`

Comment: Ah okay, so it's just not possible (yet) to get photos from a close group's album? I guess that's what I just needed know. Thank you.